# Why is my ImageView appearing before image is loaded into it (using Glide)?

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, android-glide

When I scroll through my RecyclerView quickly I notice the blank ImageView is appearing before the image is actually loaded into the ImageView (using Glide). If an image does not load successfully I would much rather it just not show anything than an empty ImageView container. I do not want the empty ImageView displayed unless it has the loaded image in it.. It is not visually pleasant to see the following empty ImageView appear before the image is loaded even if it is just for a few milliseconds before the default fade-in from Glide starts:

[image: Empty ImageView that I don't want to see]

**XML (irrelvant code removed)**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_holder_layout"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flyer_item_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    Context context;


    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row_flyer, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        ItemHolder viewHolder = new ItemHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(position);
    }


    class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        LinearLayout itemImageLinearLayout;
        ImageView itemImage;


        public ItemHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            itemImageLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.image_holder_layout);
            this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flyer_item_image);
        }


        void bind(int listIndex) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(items.get(listIndex).getImageUrl())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                    .into(itemImage);
            itemImageLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify: the Glide fade-in animation is not necesary for me. If the solution is easier with no fade-in I am ok with that.

Comment: Glide always shows a blank image before loading real image. There is no way to avoid it. Unless you use another library.

Comment: I've never seen this black image :S

Comment: you might want to cache the request so the next time it will not do another request but use the response from the previous request and prevent the blank screen the second time the user sees the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try any of the below options

1. Remove: android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" from imageView
2. Try to add a placeholder for the imageView. This will add a default image before loading the actual image

Glide.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(imageView);